# Fondo de las notificaciones Android

Tags: android, notificaciones

quiero crear en mi app una notificación y que pueda editarle el fondo, como esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se que tipo de notificación es para buscar información al respecto.

¿Alguien me podría dar una pista?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto 
[Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), puede tratar de mejorar 
su pregunta mirando este link [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada, ya que no cumple con los estándares del sitio, no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido, **lo que muestras en tu imagen NO es una notificación, es un widget**, agrega lo que has investigado o tratado por favor Javier. Revisar [ask]

Comment: Javier, te sugiero revises acerca de Widgets https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/ y realices una pregunta basada en [ask] para obtener la ayuda requerida, saludos!

Comment: creo que este link puede servirte de ayuda https://es.wikihow.com/crear-notificaciones-en-Android-Lollipop